# How to get brushes color?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, drawing, brush

There are buttons in FormDesign. If first button is clicked,

```
        brush = Brushes.Red;
```

there are codes like this for each button. I want to get brushes color for that moment. How can I get it like;

```
Color c = (color of brush);
```

this way ?

Edit : I want to keep color data in a List.

Comment: `brush.Color` ?

Comment: No, I write "brush." but "Color" doesn't appear

Comment: are you using this Brush to change the button color ?

Comment: Where does brush come from?? Example: `SolidBrush b = (SolidBrush) Brushes.Red;
    Color c = b.Color;`

Comment: In  public partial class Form1, Brush brush = Brushes.Red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code illustrates a Button Click that changes the color of Button and Color of Button is stored in a **String**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
         button1.BackColor = ((SolidBrush)brush).Color;

         string getColor;
         getColor = button1.BackColor.ToString();
         MessageBox.Show($"Color of Button1  " + getColor);

      }
```

**OR**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Brush brush1 = Brushes.Red;
     button1.BackColor = ((SolidBrush)brush1).Color;

     string getColor1;
     getColor1 = button1.BackColor.ToString();
     MessageBox.Show($"Color of Button1  " + getColor1);

     //Similarly store other button colors in a string
     string getColor2 = "Orange"; string getColor3 = "Blue"; 

     //Store these string value in a list 
     List<string> colors = new List<string>();
     colors.Add(getColor1);
     colors.Add(getColor2);
     colors.Add(getColor3);
     foreach (string color in colors) { MessageBox.Show(color); }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep colors in a List. How can I do that ? I tried to keep it as string list. It's okay to get color that way. But I can't use it. Because I will draw with colors in the list. How can I do that ?

Comment: I want to draw with them.  e.Graphics.FillPolygon( (brush with colors[0])  , points)

Comment: How can I convert that string to color and use it with brush ?

Comment: That is a completely different question, Could you post question with the requirements ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193673/how-to-draw-shape-using-colors-in-a-string-list    here it is

Answer (score 1):

[Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush(v=vs.110).aspx) is a parent class for various type of brushes; only the [SolidBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) has a Color property.

So you need to cast to `SolidBrush`:

Either:

```
Brush b1 = Brushes.Red;
Color c1 = ((SolidBrush)b1).Color;
```

or

```
SolidBrush b2 = (SolidBrush)Brushes.Red;
Color c2 = b2.Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Color using `Control.BackColor` and `Control.ForeColor`.